# strtok delimiters issue on a JSON format string

Tags: c, json, string, strtok

Using the following delimiters and sub delimiters i can't find a way to retrieve the issuer value as a whole string since i have declared "," as part of the string delimiter.
Please help.

Input String is a char* array: (Sorry, string is a cert)

```
 {"first name":"Jhon","thumbprint":"*********","issuer":"CN=dccw, OU=cswde, O=xswe, 
 L=sdewc","validto":"Mon Jan 01 22:59:59 EST 
 2018","lastname":"Doe","userid":"DJhon","valid from":"Mon Aug 15 
 00:00:00 EDT 2011","subjectInfor":"************"}
```

Code

```
 char* delim = "{}";
 char* subdelim = ":,";   

char *str1, *token, *name, *value;

int parse_count = 0;
for (str1 = stringToParse; parse_count<num ; str1 = NULL) {
    token = strtok(str1, delim);
    if (token == NULL)
        break;
    name = strtok(token, subdelim);
    value = strtok(NULL, subdelim);
    if (name == NULL || value == NULL) {
        continue;
    }
    strcpy (ptr->name, name);
    strcpy (ptr->value, value);
    ptr++;
    parse_count++;

   }
 return name_values;
}
```

Output:

```
 printf("%s=%s\n", params->name, params->value);

 first name=Jhon
 last name=Doe
 userid=DJhon
```

Comment: You cannot use strtok for this. Use a real parser.

Comment: use strtok_r or JSON lib.

Comment: Trying not to use any libs and also strtok_r wouldn't work either since i'll be running this on a server. I'm thinking of using state machine for this but i haven't worked with them before. Can anyone direct me to some good tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use a JSON library, but a simple parsing can do with sscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char data[]="{\"first name\":\"Jhon\",\"thumbprint\":\"*********\",\"issuer\":\"CN=dccw, OU=cswde, O=xswe, L=sdewc\",\"validto\":\"Mon Jan 01 22:59:59 EST 2018\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"userid\":\"DJhon\",\"valid from\":\"Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 2011\",\"subjectInfor\":\"************\"}";
    char *contents = strtok(data, "{}");//remove '{' and  '}' : note that is not included in the content
    char key[128], value[128];
    int len;
    while(2==sscanf(contents, "\"%127[^\"]\":\"%127[^\"]\",%n", key, value, &len)){
        if(!strcmp(key, "first name") || !strcmp(key, "lastname") || !strcmp(key, "userid"))
            printf("%s=%s\n", key, value);
        contents += len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Splendid. Exactly what I was looking for. I was also able to implement one using finite state machine. Thanks BLUEPIXY